# How to decode b'xx\r\x01\x03W\x85pE\x07\x177\x00\x06\xab\xa4\r\n' from TK103A gps tracker

Tags: python, gps, byte, tracker

I have 3 tk103a devices. 
Two of them send something like this: b'##,imei:359586015829802,A' - and i can work with it. 
 But one of them send b'xx\r\x01\x03W\x85pE\x07\x177\x00\x06\xab\xa4\r\n' instead of b'##,imei:359586015829802,A'.
Classic method don't help, such as .decode() with ('utf-8' or 'ascii' or 'cp866'...)
How can i fix it to a normal value?

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('192.168.1.164', 8051))
sock.listen()
conn, addr = sock.accept()

print 'connected:', addr

    while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    try:
        d = data.decode()
    except:
        raise

conn.close()

data.decode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 6: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at traccar.org and see if it can help you decipher which protocol it's using. Also, if you send a text to it to check on the status, mine is check123456, does it return a version? In my case it was GT06M_DA_V5.6_210621, and in traccar it was indeed protocol gt06.

Answer (score 0):

The received message and the expected message seem to be totally unrelated and can't be converted from one to another. Binary representation of them is below.

```
x        x        \r       \x01     \x03     W        \x85     ...
01111000 01111000 00001101 00000001 00000011 01010111 10000101

#        #        ,        i        m        e        i        ...
00100011 00100011 00101100 01101001 01101101 01100101 01101001
```

The issue is likely in something else, such as configuration of the device. You can try to reset the device to factory settings and then try again. Also ensure that you actually connect to this device, but not to something else.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it.

Comment: Factory reset didn't help. And it's very strange, this device works well with gpshome.ru service. Location, speed and etc is fine, but it initializated like GS503 tracker (phone) not TK103 or TK102. But on my server still receive b'xx\r\x01\x03W\x85pE\x07\x177\x00\x06\xab\xa4\r\n'

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to reply but for search purposes....
The ones returning ##,imei are likely genuine Coban 103 devices.

The one returning hex(or "garbage") is likely a clone using the GT06 protocol.

In PHP it becomes more legible with $incoming_hexstring = bin2hex($data);

To rewrite your script to parse the GT06 protocol is onerous, as it requires careful replies from server to device.

Personally, due to ease of use, reliability and other factors, I would try to source from the guy who seems to have Coban 103's.
The issue is, right thru out the chinese supply chain, people are injecting clone devices.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29855579)